# How to split an array into two arrays, one for even and one for odd in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am doing an exercise that consists of a program that generates 100 random numbers ranging from 1 to 1000 and saves them in an array.

I have to separate this array into two arrays, one for even numbers and one for odd numbers and print the lists.

I have managed to separate into two arrays, but when they are empty, they invent them. How can i avoid it? Any clue to improve it?

Thank you so much.

That's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(){
    int array100[100];
    int arraypar[100];
    int arrayimpar[100];

    int i, n=0, m=0;

    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        array100[i] = rand() % (1000 + 1);
        printf("%i ", array100[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        if(array100[i]%2==0){
            m++;
            arraypar[m] = array100[i];
        }
        else{
            n++;
            arrayimpar[n] = array100[i];
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n Numeros pares: \n");

    for(i=1;i<=100;i++){
        printf("%i ", arraypar[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n Numeros impares: \n");

    for(i=1;i<=100;i++){
        printf("%i ", arrayimpar[i]);
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know it.

Comment: Where do you think the problem is?

Comment: I removed the comment about code review after I re-read and saw  _"but when they are empty, they invent them"_.

Comment: When the for loop finishes, The array is completed with made-up numbers

Comment: _made-up numbers_?  Do you mean numbers that were not initially created using `rand()`

Comment: FYI. Your question has been triaged giving me the power to delete this (although I'm not going to do this this time). Somebody flagged this probably because the language of your post can only ever involve English. It is easy to figure out what "Numeros pares" and "Numeros impares" mean based on the context of your post, but please try to avoid this in the future

Comment: `for(i=1;i<=100;i++){` will result in a run-time error because your arrays all have `100` elements, indexed from `0` to `99`, not `1` to `100`.

Comment: @KamilJanowski Won't happen again. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un-initialized variables can contain anything, it is better to start of by initializing.

This

```
int array100[100];
int arraypar[100];
int arrayimpar[100];
```

Should be:

```
int array100[100] = {0};
int arraypar[100] {0};
int arrayimpar[100] = {0};
```

And since C uses 0 base array indexing, you are probably seeing a run time error; `Dereference of out-of-bounds pointer` (or similar) if the code shown in your post is the actual code you are using.

This:

```
for(i=1;i<=100;i++){
      ^  ^^
    printf("%i ", arraypar[i]);
}
```

Should be this:

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
      ^  ^
    printf("%i ", arraypar[i]);
}
```

Same for the next for loop.

Also, a suggestion to help you troubleshoot. I would start off by initializing `array100` with a known set of sequential values to easily test whether the values are being split properly:

```
int array100[100] = {1,2,6,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
                     11,12,16,14,15,16,17,18,19,
                     20,21,22,26,24,25,26,27,28,29,
                     60,61,62,66,64,65,66,67,68,69,
                     40,41,42,46,44,45,46,47,48,49,
                     50,51,52,55,54,55,56,57,58,59,
                     60,61,62,66,64,65,66,67,68,69,
                     70,71,72,77,74,75,77,77,78,79,
                     80,81,82,88,84,85,88,87,88,89,
                     90,91,92,99,94,95,99,97,98,99,100};
```

Now run your program with the `rand()` section commented out to see what you get.  If there are problems, they will be easier to see then looking at a collection of randomly generated numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

Setting the arrays with 0 (int array100[100] = {0}) I could separate elements in each array, so I finally could print it.

Answer (score 1):

You allocate 100 places for the `arrayimpar` and `arraypar` (with indexes 0..99). Usable number of elements (those you want to read) in those arrays are: `m`(for `arraypar`) and `n` (for `arrayimpar`). Why not use those variables when printing those arrays:

```
printf("\n\n Numeros pares: \n");

for(i = 1; i <= m; i++){
    printf("%i ", arraypar[i]);
}

printf("\n\n Numeros impares: \n");

for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    printf("%i ", arrayimpar[i]);
}
```

Practically, this should work, but theoretically you could get one of the arrays completely full, and the other empty. When that happens, eventually you will access 101-st element (with index 100) which doesn't exist. Try to fill these arrays from index 0 instead of 1, so you could never access 101-st element.

Answer (score 1):

Index of array starts from `0` not `1`, so your code below:

```
   for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        if(array100[i]%2==0){
            m++;
            arraypar[m] = array100[i];
        }
        else{
            n++;
            arrayimpar[n] = array100[i];
        }
    }
```

should change to:

```
   for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        if(array100[i]%2==0){
            arraypar[m] = array100[i];
            m++;
        }
        else{
            arrayimpar[n] = array100[i];
            n++;
        }
    }
```

So, when you print, you should print `m` even numbers and `n` even numbers instead of print all values in `arraypar` and `arrayimpar`.:

```
    printf("\n\n Numeros pares: \n");

    for(i=0;i < m;i++){ // if m==0, you print nothing
        printf("%i ", arraypar[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n Numeros impares: \n");

    for(i=0;i< n;i++){ // if n == 0, then you print nothing
        printf("%i ", arrayimpar[i]);
    }
```